# com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: REQUIRED_BINDING_NOT_FOUND for MDB: CIProcessingMDB

Tags: java, xml, websphere, message-driven-bean

I am writing a MDB and getting the following error:

```
[6/17/16 11:46:12:214 CDT] 0000008e SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: CIEventProccessingEJB.jar
[6/17/16 11:46:12:786 CDT] 0000008d ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: ibmasyncrsp
[6/17/16 11:46:12:788 CDT] 0000008d CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=ibmasyncrsp in BLA WebSphere:blaname=ibmasyncrsp started.
[6/17/16 11:46:13:691 CDT] 0000008e WASEJBMDOrche E   CNTR0135E: The CIProcessingMDB message-driven bean (MDB) does not have a corresponding binding in the binding file.
[6/17/16 11:46:13:760 CDT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /waslogs/ffdc/ent_analytics_01_ecbdfbfd_16.06.17_11.46.13.7035592161676382713691.txt com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.WASEJBMDOrchestrator.processEJBBindings 280
[6/17/16 11:46:13:776 CDT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /waslogs/ffdc/ent_analytics_01_ecbdfbfd_16.06.17_11.46.13.7615586609299134044474.txt com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.install 982
[6/17/16 11:46:13:805 CDT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /waslogs/ffdc/ent_analytics_01_ecbdfbfd_16.06.17_11.46.13.790206433441032084332.txt com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.stopBean 876
[6/17/16 11:46:13:805 CDT] 0000008e SharedEJBRunt E   WSVR0042E: Unable to stop CIEventProcessingEAR#CIEventProccessingEJB.jar#CIProcessingMDB: <null>
[6/17/16 11:46:13:822 CDT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /waslogs/ffdc/ent_analytics_01_ecbdfbfd_16.06.17_11.46.13.8125643984037638544208.txt com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.uninstall 1039
[6/17/16 11:46:13:836 CDT] 0000008e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /waslogs/ffdc/ent_analytics_01_ecbdfbfd_16.06.17_11.46.13.828594167492049995935.txt com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule 980
[6/17/16 11:46:13:837 CDT] 0000008e SharedEJBRunt E   WSVR0040E: addEjbModule failed for CIEventProccessingEJB.jar
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: REQUIRED_BINDING_NOT_FOUND for MDB: CIProcessingMDB
        at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.WASEJBMDOrchestrator.processEJBBindings(WASEJBMDOrchestrator.java:421)
        at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.WASEJBMDOrchestrator.processEJBJarBindings(WASEJBMDOrchestrator.java:239)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:609)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:336)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3576)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:995)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

I have tried everything. my ejb-jar.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
  <display-name>CIEventProccessingEJB</display-name>
  <ejb-client-jar>CIEventProcessingEJB.jar</ejb-client-jar> 
 </ejb-jar>
```

The mdb is running on a Was 8.5 box and I am having issues getting past this error. Please help.

Comment: First, that `REQUIRED_BINDING_NOT_FOUND` is a bug that should be reported to IBM: that identifier should be substituted with text that explains what the problem is.  I suspect the issue is that you're missing [ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) with relevant `<message-driven>`/`<jca-adapter>`.  Typically, application deployment fails unless you include bindings; how did you do the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

This errors are usually caused due to the name mismatch between the names in ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-bnd.xml. Please make sure the MDB name and JNDI name in your ibm-ejb-bnd.xml matches with the name in your ejb-jar.xml